# Why you change the site's allowed countries old saved addresses still work

Tags: checkout, customer-account, shipping-address

Initially in `Countries Options` country X was allowed.

Customer Y saved an address with country X.

Now I removed country X from `Allow Countries`. On checkout the country dropdown no longer shows country X.

But customer Y can still select to ship to his saved address which is in country X.

How can I fix it (don not allow to use saved addresses in country X)?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using one page checkout, then you need to override the method *getAddressesHtmlSelect* in *Mage_Checkout_Block_Onepage_Abstract* with the following:

```
public function getAddressesHtmlSelect($type)   
{
    if ($this->isCustomerLoggedIn()) {
        $allowed = array();
        foreach ($this->getCountryCollection() as $item) {
            $allowed[] = $item->getCountryId();
        }

        $options = array();
        foreach ($this->getCustomer()->getAddresses() as $address) {
            if (in_array($address->getCountryId(), $allowed)) {
                $options[] = array(
                    'value' => $address->getId(),
                    'label' => $address->format('oneline')
                );
            }               
        }

        if (empty($options)) {
            return '';
        }

        $addressId = $this->getAddress()->getCustomerAddressId();
        if (empty($addressId)) {
            if ($type=='billing') {
                $address = $this->getCustomer()->getPrimaryBillingAddress();
            } else {
                $address = $this->getCustomer()->getPrimaryShippingAddress();
            }
            if ($address && in_array($address->getCountryId(), $allowed)) {
                $addressId = $address->getId();
            }
        }

        $select = $this->getLayout()->createBlock('core/html_select')
            ->setName($type.'_address_id')
            ->setId($type.'-address-select')
            ->setClass('address-select')
            ->setExtraParams('onchange="'.$type.'.newAddress(!this.value)"')
            ->setValue($addressId)
            ->setOptions($options);

        $select->addOption('', Mage::helper('checkout')->__('New Address'));

        return $select->getHtml();
    }
    return '';
}
```